# show element once using jquery cookie plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to show the `<div class="cookiediv">` only once per visit (session) using jquery cookie plugin but can't get it to work (it always shows).

My code:

```
<div class="cookiediv">
    <p>in cookie div</p>
</div>

$(function () {
     if ($.cookie('the_cookie')) {
         $('.cookiediv').hide();
     } else {
         $('.cookiediv').show();
     }
     $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
 });
```

Comment: I tested that on jsfiddle and it worked fine for me. Have you checked your browsers cookie settings?

Comment: @wrxsti: can you provide your jsfiddle link please...

Comment: Just did in the answer below. :)

Comment: Yea, i tested on another computer and it worked in firefox there but not chrome. Must have corrupt cookies.

Answer (score 2):

[image: For the Naysayer...]http://jsfiddle.net/K7su8/

Same code as yours:

```
if ($.cookie('the_cookie')) {
    $('.cookiediv').hide();
} else {
    $('.cookiediv').show();
}
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

This seemed to work fine for me which leads me to two thoughts. Check your browsers settings, or make sure your jQuery.cookie.js library is listed in the document before the script you are running.

Comment: Works just fine in my browser.

Comment: Did you re-run the script again?...Click "run" at the top.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. It is hidden perfectly fine on my end. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: Must have corrupt cookies. People here are too downvote happy.

Comment: I see. Good call testing in another browser, and thanks!

Comment: are you using chrome as well patel?

Answer (score 0):

plugin docs:  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

To Set: `$.cookie("test", 1);`

To delete: `$.removeCookie("test");`

To SetTimeOut: `$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 5 });` // 5 days

To Read: `var cookieValue = $.cookie("test");`

To Answer your question, i think this could do the trick

```
 if (!$.cookie('the_cookie') == undefined) {
     $('.cookiediv').hide();
 } else {
     $('.cookiediv').show();
 }
```